# Run auto-open of the reference file

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know when I open another workbook from macro, how do I run "auto-open()" sub-procedure which is in the book I opened.

When I open the workbook manually, auto-open will run, but when I open it by macro, nothing will happen.

Comment: Is it by chance opening from a network drive?

Comment: I think when a macro is running and you open a workbook in there, other macros will not run unless the first one is completed or the other macro is called from the already running macro. Two of them cannot run simultaneously. So, you will have to call the macro from the workbook newly opened. That will pause the already running macro.

Comment: >Naresh
Thank you for your reply. I see. I didn't know it.

Comment: @braX, Thank you for your reply. The file I open is on company internal server.

Comment: If it's on a server, that means it's not on your local drive, and that means the network location needs to be added to your trusted settings in Excel in order to run macros from files in the location, as they can be dangerous.